# Python regular expression; brackets within brackets

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I know that there are SO MANY python regular expression questions here, I just cannot figure out my specific question, even with examples.

I have tried using [regex101](https://regex101.com/) but it's just not clicking.

I have these sentences:

```
[Hi]-THISISALOADOFTEXT-[text]
I-X-(blah[THIS2CAN2Have-SymbolsAndNumbers0])-ABCD-{x}A-AB
A-[This can 4 have any X1 rubbish in it]-ABCDDS-OH
A-F{a}R-(textnumber1)-AB-[ThisIsText123]-P-{d}C-(ThisCanHaveNumbers1)-W-[ThisIsSymbolsText123]
```

I just want to pull out what is between the square brackets, EXCEPT when the square brackets are enclosed by parentheses (rounded brackets).

So in the above example, it would return:

```
[Hi], [text]
...nothing returned for line 2...
[This can 4 have any X1 rubbish in it]
[ThisIsText123], [ThisIsSymbolsText123]
```

It almost works with this code:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'(\[.*?\])')
regex = re.findall(pattern,text)
```

I was trying to incorporate the 'not' like this: `?!A-Za-z0-9(\[.*?\])` that I got from the [python manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), but various attempts at this not working.

The only problem is that the above code also returns [THIS2CAN2Have-SymbolsAndNumbers0], I do not want this, as it is enclosed by parentheses.

Importantly, and where I am getting stuck, is that there can be text and numbers in between the square brackets and the rounded brackets, as in this example: (blah[THIS2CAN2Have-SymbolsAndNumbers0])

Can someone help?

As a side note, just FYI, the ultimate goal once I figure out the regex is to incorporate into a loop that says:

1. For each sentence, find text in square brackets
2. If square brackets not enclosed by parentheses (rounded brackets), do one routine.
3. elif square brackets enclosed by parentheses, do a different routine.

Edit 1:
How could I extend this, so that for the sequences that have square brackets in parentheses, the full phrase in the parenthesis are returned. So for example, the input sequences:

```
[Hi]-THISISALOADOFTEXT-[text]
I-X-(blah[THIS2CAN2Have-SymbolsAndNumbers0])-ABCD-{x}A-AB
A-[This can 4 have any X1 rubbish in it]-ABCDDS-OH
A-F{a}R-(textnumber1)-AB-[ThisIsText123]-P-{d}C-(ThisCanHaveNumbers1)-W-[ThisIsSymbolsText123]
```

Would produce the output:

```
[Hi], [text]
(blah[THIS2CAN2Have-SymbolsAndNumbers0])
[This can 4 have any X1 rubbish in it]
[ThisIsText123], [ThisIsSymbolsText123]
```

in a way that i could then do different subroutines on rounded-bracket output ' `(blah[THIS2CAN2Have-SymbolsAndNumbers0])'` from the other outputs, not in rounded brackets.

Comment: As per your new requirement try [`(?:\[[^]]*]|\([^)[]*\[[^)]*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/iwup6M/3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the two following patterns:

- Not enclosed in brackets. `\[[^]]+\](?!\))`
- Enclosed in brackets. `\[[^]]+\](?=\))`

As per your new requirement, you may use:

- Encloded in brackets and include in match `\([^[]+\[[^]]+\]\)`

My answer assumes the brackets are balanced and the closing `)` follows `]`.

In Python:

```
import re
mytext='''
[Hi]-THISISALOADOFTEXT-[text]
I-X-(blah[THIS2CAN2Have-SymbolsAndNumbers0])-ABCD-{x}A-AB
A-[This can 4 have any X1 rubbish in it]-ABCDDS-OH
A-F{a}R-(textnumber1)-AB-[ThisIsText123]-P-{d}C-(ThisCanHaveNumbers1)-W-[ThisIsSymbolsText123]
'''

print('no ():')
for i in re.findall(r'\[[^]]+\](?!\))',mytext):
    print(i)
    #do one routine

print('with ():')
for i in re.findall(r'\([^[]+\[[^]]+\]\)',mytext):
    print (i)
    #do second routine
```

Prints:

```
no ():
[Hi]
[text]
[This can 4 have any X1 rubbish in it]
[ThisIsText123]
[ThisIsSymbolsText123]
with ():
(blah[THIS2CAN2Have-SymbolsAndNumbers0])
```

Comment: your output doesn't match your code (assuming it works). `[THIS2CAN2Have-SymbolsAndNumbers0]` should be the last thing printed since it's enclosed in brackets.

Comment: ..? Does on my machine.

Comment: On my machine too! We must be special.

Comment: @FHTMitchell Really? A downvote? Did you even run the code?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Wow. Have an upvote to even it out.

Comment: Yes and it's the wrong answer. Why is `[ThisIsText123]` the last output?

Comment: @FHTMitchell Fixed.

Comment: It would help if you kept in the separators I put in otherwise we don't know where one print loop ends and the other begins.

Comment: Added your separators.

Comment: I'm wondering if such a construct is possible: `foo ( [foo] bar)` If so, it would make the code fail (would found but it shouldn't)

Comment: Just a question, is it possible to actually pull out '(blah[THIS2CAN2Have-SymbolsAndNumbers0])' instead of '[THIS2CAN2Have-SymbolsAndNumbers0]', for the items whose square brackets are surrounded by parentheses (and then keep as it is, for those that are not surrounded by parentheses)? I know this wasn't my original question, I'm just trying to understand how this could be expanded, I'm trying to learn more about regex, the examples are great.

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add some eamples of input/output for that requirement?

Comment: Thank you, I have done so under the section 'Edit 1'.